# A cycle of an irreducible Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Suppose we have a discrete-time Markov chain with $n$ states, with transition matrix $P$. The definition of irreducibility tells us that for any two states $x$ and $y$, there exists an integer $t$ such that $P^t (x,y) >0$.

But how does this imply that the states can be labelled as $s_1 , s_2 , \ldots, s_n$ such that

> $\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad $ $P(s_{i}, s_{i+1}) >0, \quad \quad $ for all $ \quad i \in \{1, \ldots, n-1 \}$ ?

Any suggestions of how to show this by definition?

This statement comes from a proof from Levin's book of Markov Chains:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. That would mean that every connected graph has a Hamiltonian path. That's not the case; consider a [star graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_%28graph_theory%29).

Comment: Please see the above attachment for the source of this claim.

Comment: @Richard: I think you're misunderstanding the text. I don't see anything there that implies that $n=|\Omega|$, as in your question. As far as I can tell, the author is merely using the obvious fact that irreducibility implies the existence of a path from any state to any state, without claiming that that path contains all states.

Comment: @Richard In other words, $n$ the length of the path is not $n$ the size of the state space.